# How much does fresh pasta yield when cooked?

Tags: pasta

While I know the yield for dried pasta, I cannot find the yield for fresh pasta, which I know is different from dried.

(My goal here is actually to calculate calories for fresh pasta based on the weight after cooking.)

Comment: I would imagine that it is lower than dried pasta (1 to 2) as it is already hydrated; and it might be different with different level of dryness of the pasta.

Comment: are you interested in yield to plan for a meal using store-bought pasta, or to make it yourself?

Comment: Searching for "fresh pasta nutrition information" yields https://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/usda/fresh-pasta and https://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/usda/fresh-pasta-(cooked) .  Which suggests 1lb of cooked pasta is ~600 Calories, while 1lb uncooked is ~1300.  Water has no calories, so 1lb of fresh pasta would cook up to 1306/594 = 2.2lbs

Comment: However, it won't be an accurate calculation of calories either way. Some of the calories leave the pasta during cooking because some of the starch is cooked out of the pasta.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>when making fresh pasta a classic ratio is 100g of flour + 1 egg per person; that roughly means 150g per person</strike> 
When cooked fresh pasta yields roughly 1,5 times the weight of raw (while dry pasta yields between 2 and 2,5 times according to type)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Yeah, the question is about the weight *after* cooking. Would you be able to add something about that?

Comment: sorry, but what is the point in weighting the pasta after cooking? the added weight is just water, and it is not constant, it depends on how much time do you leave the pasta in the water... anyway I'll try and edit my answer to make it more complete

Comment: Andrea: that's also an answer if you want to make it.  In either case, you should delete this and create a new answer instead of editing your original answer.